# derivative of a gradient

Tags: vector-analysis

just a very simple question:

I have a continuous and differentiable function $\phi$ defined on $R^3$ with its gradient $\nabla\phi$.

Could you please tell me if it makes sense to take a derivative of this gradient with respect to $\phi$?

So:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial{\phi}} \nabla \phi = ?$

Would it make sense to say $\frac{\partial}{\partial{\phi}} \nabla \phi = \frac{\partial}{\partial{\phi}}(\phi_{x}, \phi_{y},\phi_{z}) = (\phi_{xx}, \phi_{yy},\phi_{zz}) $?

Thanks for your time,
Matt

Answer (score -1):

Well from my point of view, you are thinking something but your notation of expression is describing other thing !!!! Like, what does it mean by $\nabla \phi $ ? We know in multi-variable calculus we can not express the derivative of a multi-variable function with just one scaler valued function.we need the help of vector valued function or expression .and here the $\nabla \phi$ comes into action.so derivative of $\phi$ is not a single expression (scalar valued function). So, by the derivative of $\phi$ you are just meaning $\nabla \phi $.

Now coming to your question. here, what does it mean by $\partial \phi $ ?
It is not a appropriate notation here,because here you wanting to say how $\nabla \phi$ changes as I change $\phi$ a little bit.Now,the problem is,this $\phi$ is not a single variable rather a scalar valued function.So you have to work on variable after variable of $\phi$ and component after component of $\nabla \phi$ (As,now it is a vector valued function) you can't express the whole expression as
$$\color{red}{\frac{\partial}{\partial{\phi}} \nabla \phi = \frac{\partial}{\partial{\phi}}(\phi_{x}, \phi_{y},\phi_{z}) = (\phi_{xx}, \phi_{yy},\phi_{zz})}$$ 
rather.if  $$\nabla \phi=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \phi_x \\
    \phi_y \\
    \phi_z \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
then you should compute $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial{x}}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}\nabla \phi$ individually.
And finally after dividing them then we **may**  say something like that you want. But that would yields,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial{\phi}} \nabla \phi=\frac{1}{\phi_x} \begin{bmatrix}
    \phi_{xx} \\
    \phi_{yx} \\
    \phi_{zx} \\
    \end{bmatrix}\text{(differentiating partially with respect to $x$)}$$

But it is not a completed answer though.you have to follow the procedure in respect of y and z also,to get a compact answer.It will be somehow a rigorous computation.